# Grails gant script to run test cases first and then run the application but It is giving cliScriptException

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, gant

I am writing a GANT script in grails to run unit test cases first and then it will run the if unit test cases passed .

My Script is

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsSettings")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClean")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsTest")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsRun")
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner as GSR
//includeTargets << new File ( "${grailsHome}/scripts/RunApp.groovy" )

/*target(customRun: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    // TODO: Implement script here
    depends(checkVersion, configureProxy, parseArguments, cleanTestReports)
    runApp()
    //runApp()
}*/

target(customRun: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    // TODO: Implement script here
    depends(checkVersion, configureProxy, parseArguments, cleanTestReports)
    System.setProperty("grails.env", "test")
    allTests()
    System.setProperty("grails.env", "development")
    runApp()
}

setDefaultTarget(customRun)
```

But I am getting scriptException once the test report is generated . I am not sure what wrong is in my script .

Exception is as

```
Error |
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:732)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
```

Comment: At first I don't understand what is this line `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner as GSR` doing there. This script works for me.

Comment: I just forgot to comment the line , initially i was trying to run appliation in different environment using GSR.main("test test-app")

Comment: Yes it is fixed , i have deleted the cli/scripTest file .nad that is why it was givinf the cliScriptException .

Thanks